# Dart/Flutter - на смартфоне фиксация событий от всех объектов при одном движении пальца по объектам

Tags: flutter, dart

Как получить отклики/события от всех объектов, над которыми прошёл указатель/палец при одном его движении по экрану смартфона [тап - > движение - >  убирание пальца]  - как на приложенном рис.?

Крайне желательно получить событие от каждого объекта сразу как указатель оказался над объектом, а не в конце (после Up) списком по всем объектам. Движение указателя может быть любым, а не только прямо линейным (как на рис.).

В доке и инете я не нашёл ничего что могло бы помочь решить задачу.
На Котлине эта возможность есть как минимум уже лет 7 (в нескольких приложениях на нём видел).
И если в эмуляторе Dart проводить над объектами палец (нажав палец на экран вне объектов), то объекты видят указатель, так как есть реакция/событие/появляется тень (например, видно на эмуляторе здесь  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Actions-class.html), т.е. эта функция в Dart точно есть… но вот какая - загадка…

Заранее спасибо за ответы и особенно за тот, который решит задачу.
[image: Движения указателя и список среагировавших объектов]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю вам стоит использовать [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

```
GestureDetector(
  onPanStart: (DragStartDetails details) {
    //коснулись
  },
  onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
    //перемещаемся
  },
  onPanEnd:(DragEndDetails details) {
    //отпустили
  }
)
```

Затем вы можете проверять координаты вашего пальца и ваших объектов, чтобы подсвечивать их.

Или же применить `GestureDetector` к каждому объекту и фиксировать, любое попадание в него пальца.

у `GestureDetector` довольно большое количество триггеров, которые вы можете увидеть в документации

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 

Я уже попробовал много методов (и указанный вами GestureDetector ((в нём много методов - не только onPan...)), и Listen, и MouseRegion и пр., но в них во всех возникла не понятка.

Если смотреть на эмуляторе, то всё Ок - детекторы видят "палец" (реально стрелку мышки) и проходящий над ними, и нажатый-проходящий (мышь с нажатой левой клавишей на ней), и клик (нажатие и отпускание), но вот на реальном смартфоне (я смотрю на Sony Xperia) отслеживает только клик (нажатие и отпускание) и на проход нажатого пальца не реагирует.

Как это лечить не понятно.

Comment: Не нашёл способ как получать отклик от каждого объекта (точнее задолбался его искать). Сделал как советовали выше "Затем вы можете проверять координаты вашего пальца и ваших объектов, чтобы подсвечивать их.". И хотя кода (генерируемого в цикле 300x300 объектов) получилось меньше, но получилось не мало кода на каждый Move и очень удивило что такой возможности (не на весь экран, а на каждый объект) в Dart/Flutter нет или, как минимум, его хрен найдёшь.